# FAILED: ParseException line 1:2 cannot recognize input near '(' 'Select' '*'とでます。

Tags: amazon, hadoop

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:2 cannot recognize input near '(' 'Select' '*'

と出ます。何が間違ってますか？

```
(
    Select
      *
    , Cast(Concat(Substr(timestamp, 1, 4), '-', Substr(timestamp, 5, 2), '-', Substr(timestamp, 7, 2), ' ', Substr(timestamp, 9, 2), ':', Substr(timestamp, 11, 2), ':', Substr(timestamp, 13, 2)) As timestamp) As fcd_timestamp
    From
      test
    Where
      st='${env:20151001}'
      And '${env:lastDate}' <= Substr(timestamp, 1, 8)
      And Substr(timestamp, 1, 8) <= '${env:1101}'
      And Substr(timestamp, 1, 8) <= Substr(up_time, 1, 8)
  ) axis
```

Comment: ECサイトとしてのAmazonには関係ないように見えますが、AWSのAmazonEMRをお使いなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

こちらSQLの実行エンジンはHiveということでよいでしょうか。
このクエリをサブクエリとして使うのでなければ下記のように書けば動くと思います。

```
Select
  *
, Cast(Concat(Substr(timestamp, 1, 4), '-', Substr(timestamp, 5, 2), '-', Substr(timestamp, 7, 2), ' ', Substr(timestamp, 9, 2), ':', Substr(timestamp, 11, 2), ':', Substr(timestamp, 13, 2)) As timestamp) As fcd_timestamp
From
  test
Where
  st='${env:20151001}'
  And '${env:lastDate}' <= Substr(timestamp, 1, 8)
  And Substr(timestamp, 1, 8) <= '${env:1101}'
  And Substr(timestamp, 1, 8) <= Substr(up_time, 1, 8)
```

このクエリの結果を更に他のクエリに与える場合にはご質問のように書くことができますが、その場合には上位に位置するクエリが必要になります。

```
SELECT
  axis.hoge
FROM
(
  -- 質問のクエリ
) axis
```